# Capture a window inside my form

Tags: winforms, delphi, pascal, capture, hwnd

I want to capture a window inside my form, how can I do that? I remember seeing a code that did this. It worked with the window handle. It behaves kind of like WinRAR's extraction window:
[image: wrar]

Comment: Set the Parent property of the to "captured" form

Comment: What does "capture" mean? You've shown two pictures of Winrar's extraction window, but that doesn't communicate to me what its behavior is. Please use words to describe what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, English isn't my main language. I actually found what I wanted (but it didn't exactly work):

```
var
  hWindow: hwnd;
begin
  hWindow := FindWindow(nil,PChar(Edit1.Text)); //Edit1.Text is the window's handle
  if hWindow <> 0 then
  begin
    Form1.ParentWindow := hWindow;
  end else
    ShowMessage('Window not found!');
end;
```

The reason I wanted something like this is because some applications that run on fullscreen present glitches because of the wrong refresh rate on my monitor. By doing this I'd force the application to run on the known "borderless" mode. But it didn't work with DirectX apps. Sorry for the inconvenience.